# Which Box2D-like physics engine parameters need pixel conversion?

Tags: box2d, physics, units-of-measurement, physics-engine, farseer

The official guide does not have any useful details on the matter:

http://www.box2d.org/manual.html

Position is an obvious one. What about velocity? Density? Anything else?

Update: the context is wrapping/interfacing a physics engine to make it more usable. E.g. units of measure in the game editor should be consistent.

Comment: If you start rounding physics values to integer pixels your simulation is likely to explode, so the short answer is "none of them" ?

Comment: Have I completely misinterpreted your question? If you mean unit conversion not rounding, then just write the units for every value out and convert the ones that don't match.  if position needs converting because it is in meters, then m, m/s, m/s/s, kg/m/m/m all need converting, because they all have meters in.

Comment: @AndyNewman Yes :), but thank you for the effort. Second comment is closer to what I am looking for - you have confirmed my thoughts. I have accepted your answer, but feel free to expand it with the second comment if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every thing you specify in physics will have units.  If you decide that physics is working in meters and your editor works in pixels then you will need to convert everything that has meters in its units.  It is probably easiest to just write them all out.

- position: m
- velocity: m/s
- acceleration: m/s/s
- density: kg/m/m/m

All of those contain meters, so all of those will need converting.
Beware of hidden ones:

- force: N
- F = ma  =>   N = kg m/s/s

So if you want to specify force in a meaningful way instead of just an arbitrary number that people tweak, force needs converting because it is implicitly measured using meters ...